How to convert Legacy Named Credentials to new External Credentials?
I have a set of legacy named credentials connecting from one SF org to another, using OAuth2 protocol.
Legacy credentials don't specify the Authentication Flow Type.
Instead, they attempt to log in to the external site upon editing.
Whereas when I create an External Credential, it doesn't login or otherwise specify the user, but does require a flow type.
What do I need to know to convert these Legacy credentials to External Credentials?
